# Where Can I find this Machlokes about the 13 Middot of Drush?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rashi, machlokes, tosfot, drush

Several years ago, I came across the following machlokes between Rashi and Tosfot in Shas Bavli.

Rashi said that all 13 middos of drush require a mesorah except for Kal Vachomer, and Tosfot said all 13 middos of drush do not require a mesorah except for a Gezeirah Shava.

I can no longer remember where this is. Does anyone know where one can find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I subsequently found the location. It can be found on Sukkah 31a.